# Apply CSS for empty element including space and comments

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply some styles for the empty div elements including the div have only comments or spaces.

My HTML Structure like below.

```
<div id="test">
    <div>Some content inside is there</div>
    <div></div>
    <div><!--This is treating as empty--></div>
    <div>   </div>
    <div>
      <!--This also should treat as empty-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to use the pseudo-class `:empty`,but it is targeting only 2nd and 3rd elements. I know we can use javascript to achieve this. Is there any solution using only CSS?

```css
div:empty {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div>Some content inside is there</div>
    <div></div>
    <div><!--This is treating as empty--></div>
    <div>   </div>
    <div>
      <!--This also should treat as empty-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why can you not just add a class to the empty divs and target them that way? (Or vice-versa, add a class to the divs with content.)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/

Comment: I don't have any control on the html code. Anyway thanks for the link you shared. I got the answer and also noticed that you have answered that question :)